# MySQL - Find Client with most transactions on a table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table of transactions that stores the transaction id, the client id and the total amount of each transaction.
How do I find the client with more transactions? Im using PHP and Mysql, but im sure there is a way to do this inside the SQL query.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's lots of ways to do it, here's one

```
SELECT COUNT(client_id) AS transaction_count, client_id 
    FROM transactions
    GROUP BY client_id
    ORDER BY COUNT(client_id) DESC
    LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM `Transactions` ORDER BY `amount` DESC LIMIT 1

Answer (score 0):

One solution is:

```
SELECT `client_id`, COUNT(*) AS c_num 
FROM `transaction` 
GROUP BY `client_id` 
ORDER BY `c_num` ASC
LIMIT 1
```